# error en recyclerVIew (Collections.reverse)

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, recyclerview

Tengo un grave problema haciendo una app. Quise hacer un bloc de notas, le agrego las notas pero quería que el orden de la entrada de notas fuera al revés, es decir, la ultima nota fuese la que se mostrara primero, como estaba en un `ArrayList` las notas pues use esto:

```
private Note getNote(int position) {
    Collections.reverse(notes);
    return notes.get(position);
}
```

y bien me los cambio pero ahora sale un problema al ejecutar la app ingresas una nota bien, ingresas la segunda nota y la primera nota toma el valor de la segunda (como si se hubiese repetido), colocas la tercera nota y sale como debería ser
ejemplo

> *primera nota agregada = a --- se muestra en pantalla a
>
> **segunda nota agregada = b --- se muestra en pantalla b (primera nota), 
>                                                           b(segunda nota)
>
> *tercera nota agregada = c --- se muestra en pantalla a(primera nota)
>                                                          b(segunda nota)
>                                                          c(tercera nota)

Les mando el código del adaptador:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private NoteEventListener listener;
    private boolean multiCheckMode = false;


    public NotesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notes = notes;
    }


    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_layout, parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(v);
    }

    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(NoteHolder holder, int position) {
        int c=notes.size();


        final Note note = getNote(position);
        if (note != null) {
            holder.noteText.setText(note.getNoteText());
            holder.noteDate.setText(NoteUtils.dateFromLong(note.getNoteDate()));            // init note click event
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onNoteClick(note);
                }
            });

            // init note long click
            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    listener.onNoteLongClick(note);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // check checkBox if note selected
            if (multiCheckMode) {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show checkBox if multiMode on
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(note.isChecked());
            } else holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide checkBox if multiMode off


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {


        return notes.size();
    }

    private Note getNote(int position) {
        Collections.reverse(notes);
        return notes.get(position);
    }


    /**
     * get All checked notes
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public List<Note> getCheckedNotes() {
        List<Note> checkedNotes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Note n : this.notes) {
            if (n.isChecked())
                checkedNotes.add(n);
        }

        return checkedNotes;
    }


    class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView noteText, noteDate;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            noteDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_date);
            noteText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }


    public void setListener(NoteEventListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setMultiCheckMode(boolean multiCheckMode) {
        this.multiCheckMode = multiCheckMode;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

(agrego que el código en verdad es sacado de un tutorial de bloc de notas y aun no estoy del todo claro de muchas cosas,apenas estoy aprendiendo y si me sugieren algún libro, canal o medio para seguir estudiando lo agradecería un montón)

Comment: Has intentado hacer el reverse en el constructor de la clase en lugar de en `getNote`? Algo como `this.notes = notes; Collections.Reverse(this.notes)` y quitarlo de `GetNote`

Comment: Puede que esta otra pagina te sirva de utilidad: [link a explicación recycler view](http://www.developandsys.es/recycler-view/) [link a la pagina](http://www.developandsys.es/) Aqui tienes explicaciones sobre las funcionalidades básicas de android, a mi me vino muy bien para comprender algunas cosas.

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando sqlite para llenar el Recycler?